# Filter for 3 levels, based on object.object.object.property with object.property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to filter the object below by `year._id` and `major._id`:

```js
student = {
  _id: ,
  name: ,
  timetable: {
    name: ,
    _id: ,
    academic_year: {
      _id: ,
      name:
    },
    major: {
      _id: ,
      name: ,
      abbreviation_name:
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="student in students |filter:{timetable: {academic_year: {_id: yearSearchIdKey}}} ></span>
```

and this

```
<span ng-repeat="student in students | filter:{timetable: [{academic_year: [{_id: yearSearchIdKey}]}]} ></span>
```

But neither one works.
How can I do it?

Comment: What do you have finally? An `object` or an `array`? I'm asking because you're using `students`, but you show us just an `object` called `student`. Also you're printing nothing in your view (inside <span> tag).. If it's an `object`, you can't perform a `filter` directly, you have to parse it before..

Comment: @ GeorgethantZin did my answer work for you?

Comment: yeap. XD. it did. sorry for my late reply. :P

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have an `array`, so you `filter` must be like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="student in students | filter: { student: { timetable: { academic_year: { _id: yearSearchIdKey }}}}" ng-bind="student | json"></span>
```

Working `code`:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.students = [{
      "student": {
        "_id": "studentId1",
        "name": "student1",
        "timetable": {
          "name": "time1",
          "_id": "timeId1",
          "academic_year": {
            "_id": "academic_yearId1",
            "name": "academic_year1",
          },
          "major": {
            "_id": "majorId1",
            "name": "major1",
            "abbreviation_name": "majorAbbr1"
          }
        }
      }
    }];
  }

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="yearSearchIdKey" placeholder="Search...">
  <hr>
  <pre ng-repeat="student in students | filter: { student: { timetable: { academic_year: { _id: yearSearchIdKey }}}}" ng-bind="student | json"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```